# problem with showing tables in html

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to show 2 tables in html first at center and second at right like this pic.

[image: The layout I need]

[Link to the layout image](http://mehdi9torki.persiangig.com/image/Untitled.jpg)

But I don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: please see the image i want to design two tables like the picture

Comment: I still don't get it. Are you asking for two tables next to each other, one with 5 rows and the other with 3?

Comment: even with the chunks of the border missing?

Comment: I hope your actual tables have more than one column each (otherwise you should almost certainly be using lists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use floats for a nice CSS solution:

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#table1 { float: left; width: 60%; }
#table2 { float: right; width: 39%; }
```

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="table1">...</table>
    <table id="table2">...</table>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hYAwT/)

Set widths according to your taste.

The `overflow: hidden` is needed because otherwise `#container` would collapse because by default `float`s are not taken into account when calculating parent's height.

Comment: All else being equal, it doesn't actually matter if #container collapses … or exists, for the purposes of this question.

Comment: @David That's true. I just wanted to provide some help with further possible problems.

Comment: it isn't possible with out css?

Comment: You want to do presentation. CSS was designed to do presentation of HTML and other markup documents. Why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: @mehdi You would have done this without CSS **>10 years ago**. That's a long time in web development. Nowadays if you want to create anything on the web, you should not avoid CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Or in a div framework...

html

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <table>
//left table
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
   <table>
//right table
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container{
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
#left {
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:100%;
width:60%;
position:absolute;
}
#right{
top:0px;
left:60%;
height:100%;
width:40%;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a sledge hammer of a tool. If applied carefully to just the right spot it can do some useful stuff, but throwing it around wildly tends to destroy layouts. It should generally be a last resort.

Answer (score -2):

```
<table width="100%">

<tr><td width="33%"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%"> First table goes here </td></tr>
<tr><td width="33%"> Second table goes here</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @david.. i can pull out 100's of articles which support tables too. it depends on the problem at hand... and for cross browser support u definitely need tables

Comment: @Kasturi Are you serious about your cross-browserness statement? Tables for layout is a technique from the far past, all browsers (that at least 0.1% uses nowadays) support enough CSS for this simple task.

Comment: @Kasturi Every day I fight it. Tables (for layout) are not needed even for IE6, which is 10 years old.